# Flutter List of TextField Values Disappear When the List Changes

Tags: flutter

I have a list of TextFields generated from a list.
I type values into the fields.
I delete an element from the list.
I want the text field for that element to disappear.
I want all the other text fields to remain as they are.

In messing around with my code, the behaviour I get is either: all the fields after the deleted one get emptied, or all of the fields are always empty even when I type in.

Attempt:

```
class Experiment extends StatefulWidget {
  List<String> list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];

  Experiment({super.key});

  @override
  State<Experiment> createState() => _ExperimentState();
}

class _ExperimentState extends State<Experiment> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: List.generate(widget.list.length, (index) {
        var elem = widget.list[index];

        return Row(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
                width: 100,
                child: Thing(key: ValueKey(elem))),
            SizedBox(
                width: 100,
                child: MaterialButton(
                  child: Text("delete"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      widget.list.removeAt(index);
                    });
                  },
                )),
          ],
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}

class Thing extends StatelessWidget {
  TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  Thing({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: textEditingController,
    );
  }
}
```

(Yes, my text field is wrapped in another component.)

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your all your textfield is being cleared is when you press delete your widget is being rebuilt by setState

When you call setState, it will schedule build causing build method to be called. So, when you press delete, your build method gets called causing your **Thing** widget to rebuild again and your textEditingController gets reinitialized. One solution is pass the textEditingController from your parent controller.

```
class Experiment extends StatefulWidget {
  List<String> list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];

  Experiment({super.key});

  @override
  State<Experiment> createState() => _ExperimentState();
}

class _ExperimentState extends State<Experiment> {
  late List<TextEditingController> controllers;

  @override
  void initState() {
    controllers = widget.list.map((s) => TextEditingController()).toList();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: List.generate(widget.list.length, (index) {
        var elem = widget.list[index];

        return Row(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
                width: 100,
                child: Thing(
                    textEditingController: controllers[index],
                    key: ValueKey(elem))),
            SizedBox(
                width: 100,
                child: MaterialButton(
                  child: Text("delete"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      widget.list.removeAt(index);
                      controllers.removeAt(index);
                    });
                  },
                )),
          ],
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}

class Thing extends StatelessWidget {
  TextEditingController textEditingController;
  
  Thing({required this.textEditingController, super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: textEditingController,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I already test your code, the problem happened due to putting the textEdittingController inside the different component so when you do setState, the textEdittingController gets rebuilt and then lost the value inside.

Here is the fixed version:

```
class Experiment extends StatefulWidget {
  List<String> list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];

  Experiment({super.key});

  @override
  State<Experiment> createState() => _ExperimentState();
}

class _ExperimentState extends State<Experiment> {
   List<TextEditingController> controllers = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
     // Initialize the controllers list with an instance for each element in the list
    controllers = List.generate(
      widget.list.length,
      (index) => TextEditingController(text: widget.list[index]),
    );
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: List.generate(widget.list.length, (index) {
        var elem = widget.list[index];

        return Row(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
                width: 100,
                child: Thing(key: ValueKey(elem), textEditingController: controllers[index],)),
            SizedBox(
                width: 100,
                child: MaterialButton(
                  child: Text("delete"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      widget.list.removeAt(index);
                    });
                  },
                )),
          ],
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}

class Thing extends StatelessWidget {
  TextEditingController textEditingController;

  Thing({super.key,required this.textEditingController});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: textEditingController,
    );
  }
```

}

so, how I fixed this is instead of creating the textEdittingController inside the component, I take it out and initialize them on the parent widget, so they will not get rebuilt again and again.